# c++: Is table lookup vectorizable for small lookup-table

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, avx

I want to vectorize the following snippet of code with SIMD intrinsics is this possible?

```
unsigned char chain[3][3] = { 
            3,  2, 1,    //  y    --> x
            4, -1, 0,    //  | 
            5,  6, 7     //  |
            };           //  v    

std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<int> y;    
//initialize x, y

std::vector<int> chain_code(x.size());

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i
     chain_code[i] = chain[x[i]][y[i]];
```

**EDIT:**

Support for: SSE - SSE4.2 and AVX

Architectur: Sandy Bridge i5 2500

Comment: Yes it is possible with gather instructions.

Comment: Most SIMD architectures have `permute` instruction(s) which can be used for fast lookups from tables of up to 16 or even 32 elements. Please specify which CPU architecture and which SIMD instruction set you are targetting for a more specific answer.

Comment: how is this possible?

Comment: Start by looking at `_mm_shuffle_epi8`. Also consider making all your types 8 bit ints, which will save a lot of packing/unpacking. I expect someone will provide a more complete answer in due course, but if not then I'll expand further when I have more time.

Comment: Consider packing the entire array into an integer, then doing an in-register lookup. Unfortunately your data includes -1, otherwise you could pack it as nine 3-bit elements which fit into a 32-bit integer. An in-register lookup means you access the relevant element via right shift, followed by masking with AND, which are all vectorizable operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make your `x`, `y`, `chain_node` 8-bit integers (instead of 32-bit ones), then you can process 16 values at once.
Here is the code using SSSE3:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> x;
std::vector<uint8_t> y;    
...
int n = x.size();
std::vector<uint8_t> chain_code(n);

//initialize table register
__m128i table = _mm_setr_epi8(
    chain[0][0], chain[0][1], chain[0][2], 99,
    chain[1][0], chain[1][1], chain[1][2], 99,
    chain[2][0], chain[2][1], chain[2][2], 99,
    99, 99, 99, 99
);

int b = (n / 16) * 16;
for (int i = 0; i < b; i += 16) {
    //load 16 X/Y bytes
    __m128i regX = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&x[i]);
    __m128i regY = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&y[i]);
    //shift all X values left by 2 bits (as 16-bit integers)
    __m128i regX4 = _mm_slli_epi16(regX, 2);
    //calculate linear indices (x * 4 + y)
    __m128i indices = _mm_add_epi8(regX4, regY);
    //perform 16 lookups
    __m128i res = _mm_shuffle_epi8(table, indices);
    //store results
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&chain_code[i], res);
}
for (int i = b; i < n; i++)
    chain_code[i] = chain[x[i]][y[i]];
```

The fully working version of this code is [here](http://pastebin.com/6sVbHGZD). Generated assembly is quite simple (MSVC2013 x64):

```
movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
psllw   xmm1, 2
paddb   xmm1, xmm0
movdqa  xmm0, xmm6
pshufb  xmm0, xmm1
movdqu  XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax], xmm0
```

P.S. I guess you'll have various performance issues with `std::vector` containers. Perhaps unaligned accesses are no longer expensive, but filling vector with zeros will certainly happen. And it can take more time than the vectorized code.

Comment: Would you add the command line necessary to compile your full code with gcc? I cannot get it to compile, but I might be missing the right options. Is uint8_t the correct datatype for your table? Should it not be int8_t to allow for the single negative entry?

Comment: @CarlChristian, see on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3hbYfKbEh  Just make sure to set `-mssse3` and replace -1 to 255 (narrowing conversion warning).